# Best way to combine 7 different shapefiles into one geodatabase

Tags: arcgis-10.0, spatial-database

I have 7 different point shapefiles, and want to join them into one geodatabase. What would be the best method to do this in ArcGIS10?

Comment: Are you looking to have 7 feature classes in the output geodatabase or just 1 of them combined?  If just 1 - use the Append Geoprocessing tool

Comment: I would like to have 1 of them all combined. What is the difference between merging them all together and using the append geoprocessing tool?

Comment: Merging creates a NEW featureclass while append would add 6 of your featureclasses to one existing featureclass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The linked thread explains pretty well the difference between merge and append.  In your case, I think, if you don't have a feature class to put the 7 shapefile into, use the Merge tool.

[Measuring performance difference between Merge and Append in ArcGIS Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/28244/is-there-a-difference-in-performance-between-merge-and-append-in-arcgis)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add them all in separately, right click the geodatabase, and import feature class (multiple)

You can also merge them all together, and do the same to have one shapefile containing the 7 shapefile's attributes' in the geodatabase.